Why can't VS Code show Flutter errors in a particular file?
I am using flutter bloc for authentication when making some changes in AuthState file i accidently made AuthBloc file unable to find errors and if i commented all the imports the i get all the import related errors but if I uncomment it back, the errors were still there, by commenting stuffs i found out
class AuthStateNeedsVerification extends AuthState {
  const AuthStateNeedsVerification({
    required super.isLoading,
  });

if i used this line of code VScode's linting doesn't work in AuthBloc file.
class AuthStateNeedsVerification extends AuthState {
  const AuthStateNeedsVerification({
    required bool isLoading,
  }) : super(isLoading: isLoading);
}

But this code without the super parameters works fine.
Why this problem exists in flutter.
edit: Not sure what the problem really is but it exists in the AuthBloc file only and its only due to the AuthState file. And i am pretty much sure its due to super parameters.

What do you mean by "gets crazy"?  That's not very helpful.  And why do you think this is a flutter problem and not a VSCode problem?

it might be a vscode problem but in my opinion its related to new super parameters.

by crazy i mean it acts unexpectedly for just a single file

"Unexpectedly" is not any better than "crazy".  WHAT HAPPENS?

Sure, let me explain linting just doesn't seem to work if I use super parameters, really not sure if that's the case but, i tried resetting the linter even restated vs code multiple times and even restated my pc but nothing really helped.
